# Не получается достать данные из mysql в laravel, что делать?

Tags: mysql, laravel

на сборке laravel/react добавил phpmyadmin все работает нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке достать данные в json выходит ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже попробовал много всего, вот env и database файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых, убедитесь, что у вас mysql работает на 3306 порту. Если всё так, попробуйте изменить параметр `DB_HOST` с localhost на 127.0.0.1 Не знаю почему, но на некоторых машинах это помогает. Ну и на всякий случай запустите `artisan config:clear`, вдруг у вас закэшировались старые конфигурационные данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле database удалил сокет, в .env добавил строчку

```
UNIX_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```